# Какое устройство можно использовать для получения расстояния до предмета в компьютерном приложении?

Tags: web-camera

Вдруг кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной задачей ранее.
Надо с помощью компьютерного приложения получить точку попадания предмета в мишень.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1 - это деревянный щит (мишень - вид с боку)[это базовая матрица точек].
В нее втыкается топор или нож или какой-нибудь предмет.
Какой девайс можно использовать, чтобы измерить расстояние (получить матрицу точек нового [добавленного] предмета)?
В принципе, ближайшая точка нового предмета к базовой матрице - и будет точкой попадания.
По идее - Для получения координаты на квадратном щите, понадобятся два таких устройства.

Comment: любой устройство с объективом и возможностью следить за изображением можно использовать. Вебкамера, например.

Comment: Одну камеру сверху, другую сбоку.

Comment: Я прошу прощения...    как с помощью веб-камеры получить расстояние до предмета с точностью +/- несколько миллиметров?

Comment: Ээээ...  возможно что-то подобное 3D сканеру?   Тогда массив точек после попадания (предмет в мишени) минус базовый массив точек = массив точек предмета, точка этого массива на минимальном расстоянии находящаяся от базового массива = точка попадания.

Comment: Можно и одной камерой обойтись. Потребуются примерно такие преобразования изображения: 
1. Перспективное преобразование - вырезка по контуру и растягивание в прямоугольную картинку мишени.
2. Размер мишени известен, значит можно посчитать сколько пикселей в миллиметре или миллиметров в пикселе
3. на основании этого получаем расстояния от краёв мишени до предмета в ней